# Python mutual exlusive log messages depending on level

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm looking for recommendations/pattern for the following issue

In my script I have situations where I would like to log only 1 of 2 messages depending on the logger level, so in my script I have something along these lines

```
logger.info('AA') # Less detailed message
logger.debug('AABB') # More detailed message
```

When the logger level is set to DEBUG, both messages will be logged. The reason I don't want that is because the DEBUG message is a duplicate of the INFO level but with more details.

Options I have considered

1-Check the logger level

```
if logger.getEffectiveLevel() == logging.INFO:
    logger.info('AA') # Less Detailed Message
elif logger.getEffectiveLevel() == logging.DEBUG:
    logger.debug('AABB') # More Detailed Message
```

Doesn't feel like the right thing to be checking the level as this is basically the work the logging module should be doing on behalf of my script

2-Make the DEBUG message only log the extra level of detail that the INFO message doesn't log. The problem with this approach is that this is a multi-threaded script, and there is no guarantee that the DEBUG message will show up right after the INFO message in the script because messages of another thread might come in between, so that makes it very tricky to find both messages in the log to be able to get the full debug message

```
logger.info('AA')
logger.debug('BB')
```

Anyone have any good ideas/suggestions?

TIA